# Scroll to a specific position on a page using Javascript / Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

It is possible to move to a certain position on a page using `#elementId`. How can I do the same thing using Javascript / Jquery. When a JS function is called, I want to scroll to the specific position on that page.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

After much googling I found that you just need to do this:

```
location.hash = "elementId"
```

Comment: That's a really nice one, thanks!

Comment: window.scrollTo(x-coord, y-coord)
window.scrollTo(options)

Answer (score 18):

Another solution is [scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

```
document.getElementById("elementID").scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: when *behavior:smooth* will be available , this will be the perfect solution (as right now it just jumps - which is not ideal UX)

Answer (score 15):

Here's an example function that I tested on today's [New York Times front page](http://www.nytimes.com/) using the browser console:

```
function scrollToElement(pageElement) {    
    var positionX = 0,         
        positionY = 0;    

    while(pageElement != null){        
        positionX += pageElement.offsetLeft;        
        positionY += pageElement.offsetTop;        
        pageElement = pageElement.offsetParent;        
        window.scrollTo(positionX, positionY);    
    }
}

var pageElement = document.getElementById("insideNYTimesHeader");
scrollToElement(pageElement);
```

Comment: Smart coding! This is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Can you even add smooth scrolling with this?

Comment: @nwillo `window.scrollTo({ top: positionY, left: positionX, behavior: 'smooth' });`

Answer (score 2):

you can use [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) to scroll up.

you can use [**this**](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) plugin too