# Change default HTML loading point

Tags: html

Is it possible to make an html file load from the middle of it? I.e. whenever a person accesses that page the thing that is shown is something say in the bottom of the page.

The person then can scroll up to reach to another location in the page.

Comment: do you want the server to return the center part first, or do you just want the browser to automatically zoom to the center when the page loads?

Comment: I just want the browser to automatically zoom to the center when the page loads for any browser anytime and for anyone who loads it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished by use of an anchor

```
<a name="anchorid"></a>
```

When loading the page with the anchor, it will jump to that position after rendering
Example http://yoursite.com/#anchorid

The other option would be to use JavaScript.

There are many questions on StackOverflow already answering this question.

1) [Scroll to a specific position on a page using Javascript / Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355482/scroll-to-a-specific-position-on-a-page-using-javascript-jquery)

2) [jQuery jump or scroll to certain position, div or target on the page from button onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15158937/jquery-jump-or-scroll-to-certain-position-div-or-target-on-the-page-from-button)