# How to page scrolling like this?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

[Scrollbar with points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EPSw.png) 
Can someone explain to me (or has a good tutorial for it) how this scrolling thing works? I don't know how I should google it.

This looks like a side scrollbar, and when I scroll down, it switches one Point down, and the page changes. Are there thew tutorials on how to create this? Please send me some info about it, because I really wanna know how to create this.

Comment: Please show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you mean

Comment: Your image seems to just show a circle - I have absolutely no idea what the scenario is. Please include more description of what is to happen and include in your question the code you have have tried so far.

Comment: Do you want to light up a dot based on the section you are currently scrolling in? Just to make sure we are on the same page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is an other question that may help you:

[Scroll to a specific position on a page using Javascript / Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355482/scroll-to-a-specific-position-on-a-page-using-javascript-jquery)

and I think these links may help you:

https://www.codespeedy.com/scroll-to-a-specific-position-in-javascript/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

They speak about:

.scrollTo

scroll-behavior

scrollIntoView()

scrollIntoView(alignToTop)

scrollIntoView(scrollIntoViewOptions)

You better read all articles.

Comment: Answers which are just links may not be very helpful to future readers if those links move or are deleted. Please include an explanation of the answer and if appropriate an example snippet.